# Maven: Reporting warnings during regular compile, but not for generated sources

Tags: maven, compiler-warnings

We have a Maven project that uses WSDL files that are turned into Java source files and later compiled.

When this project used Ant, we compiled the generated Java source file and the normal developer written Java source files separately. This allowed me to turn on deprecation and warnings on compiling the developer written Java files, but off for compiling the WSDL generated Java files. I want the developers to fix their warnings and deprecations, but I can't hold the developers responsible for code that the WSDLs generated.

Now, we've moved the project over to Maven, and I would like to do the same thing: Compile the WSDL generated Java source code without the warnings and compile the developer written Java source code with the warnings. Is it possible to do with Maven? (I mean without writing it in Ant and embedding that in the `pom.xml`).

---

#### POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vegicorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>crypto</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>2.0.4</version> <!--package version-->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <axis2.version>1.5.6</axis2.version>
        <maven.dir>${project.build.directory}/maven/crypto.jar</maven.dir>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugins</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                        <arg>Xmaxwarns</arg>
                        <arg>9999</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestSections>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>Build-Information</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Project-Name>${env.JOB_NAME}</Project-Name>
                                    <Build-Number>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                                    <SVN-Revision>${env.SVN_REVISION}</SVN-Revision>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>Module-Information</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Group-ID>${project.groupId}</Group-ID>
                                    <Artifact-ID>${project.artifactId}</Artifact-ID>
                                    <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                        </manifestSections>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>com.safenet.tokenization.wsclient</packageName>
                            <wsdlFile>src/main/wsdl/SafeNetTokenizer.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                            <skipBuildXML>true</skipBuildXML>
                            <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite> 
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <targetSourceFolderLocation>generated-sources</targetSourceFolderLocation> 
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reuseFork>true</reuseFork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                 <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- COMPILE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using cxf maven plugin? Post your pom config, especially maven-compiler-plugin and cxf.

Comment: Okay, POM posted. We're using the axis2 plugin. There are at least three different WSDL2Java plugins I know of. I didn't post the pom because I didn't think there was anything in it that would be important to this particular issue. However, if it'll help...

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured out how to do this, but I am not enamored with the solution:

- Define two separate *maven-compiler-plugin* executions. One called *default-compile* where I compile the WSDL code, and one called *main-compile* where I compile the rest of the code.
- Use `<includes/>` and `<excludes>` in the *main-compiler-plugin* execution configurations to include and exclude the code I want to compile.
- I still need the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to define two separate source.

The `default-compile` is always executed (I couldn't figure out a way to turn it off) even if I don't have a configuration `default-compile`. That would automatically compile everything before looking at my two defined *maven-compile-plugin* plugin executions. To get around this, I named the WSDL compile `default-compile`.

Here's the mavin-compiler-plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/com/safenet/**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/vegicorp/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>main-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/com/vegicorp/**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/safenet/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                    <arg>Xmaxwarns</arg>
                    <arg>9999</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [David W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913647) very useful.  Unfortunately, I could not find an easy way to separate `generated-sources` for my current project using `<includes>`/`<excludes>` (and `<testIncludes>`/`<testExcludes>` for `default-testCompile`), since they appear to be checked against paths relative to `compileSourceRoots`.

The solution that worked best for me is to specify `<compileSourceRoots>` for each `<execution>`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <configuration>
        <compileSourceRoots>
          <compileSourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger/src/main/java</compileSourceRoot>
        </compileSourceRoots>
        <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>compile-with-warnings</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <compileSourceRoots>
          <compileSourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</compileSourceRoot>
        </compileSourceRoots>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>default-testCompile</id>
      <configuration>
        <compileSourceRoots>
          <compileSourceRoot>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</compileSourceRoot>
        </compileSourceRoots>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This has the advantage of no longer requiring `build-helper-maven-plugin` (since `${project.compileSourceRoots}` is ignored), but the disadvantage that since `${project.compileSourceRoots}` is ignored, `compileSourceRoot` for each generator plugin must be added to an `<execution>` explicitly or it will not be compiled.